# Como encontrar um elemento dentro de um array de objetos pelo Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

Tenho dois **arrays**, onde um deles contém números inteiros (**array1**) e outro contém objetos (**array2**) com propriedades como *Id*, *Descricao e NumeroVinculo*.

Preciso encontrar e remover do todos os elementos do **array2** que correspondem a cada inteiro(valor) do **array1**.

Já tentei utilizar a função `.find(x => x.Id === index)` porém não obtive sucesso.

Estou utilizando `JavaScript`, `jQuery` e `KnockoutJS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se usar o [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para remover determinado índice do array.

```js
let a1 = [2,4,6],
    a2 = [
    {id: 1, nome: "Teste 1"},
    {id: 2, nome: "Teste 2"},
    {id: 3, nome: "Teste 3"},
    {id: 4, nome: "Teste 4"},
    {id: 5, nome: "Teste 5"},
    {id: 6, nome: "Teste 6"}
    ];

// removendo os IDs pares em a1
a2.forEach( (item, index) => {
    // se o id do array de objetos estiver em a1
    if (a1.indexOf(item.id) > -1)
        a2.splice(index,1) // entao remove
});

console.log(a2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
var array1 = [1,2,3]

var array2 = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4},
    {id: 5},
    {id: 6}
];

var diferenca = []

jQuery.grep(array2, function(item) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(item.id, array1) == -1) diferenca.push(item);
});

console.log(diferenca)
```